# Batch Script FTP Looping Through Host List

Tags: loops, batch-file, ftp, dos

I have the following batch script to FTP and pull back a file from a host.  (ftpscript.bat)

```
@echo off
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF

open host1
username
password
cd apples
bin
hash
get fileName.txt fileName.host1
disconnect
```

I have the following text file that contains a list of hosts.  (hosts.txt)

```
     host1
     host2
     host3
     host4
```

How can I loop through each host in the file, each line of the file, and run this script with the host variable in it?

This is an example of how I want it to look like when it runs:

```
@echo off
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF

open host1
username
password
cd apples
bin
hash
get fileName.txt fileName.host1
disconnect

open host2
username
password
cd apples
bin
hash
get fileName.txt fileName.host2
disconnect

open host3
username
password
cd apples
bin
hash
get fileName.txt fileName.host3
disconnect

open host4
username
password
cd apples
bin
hash
get fileName.txt fileName.host4
disconnect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to append all the hosts you have in the `hosts.txt` to the existing `ftpscript.bat` script then this should work

```
for /f %%a in (hosts.txt) do (
echo open %%a
echo username
echo password
echo cd apples
echo bin
echo hash
echo get fileName.txt fileName.%%a
echo disconnect
echo.
) >>ftpscript.bat
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks!! Everything in the FOR just needs to be echoed so it outputs to the file.  It will create the ftpscript.bat for me to run.